# What is the name of the moment when the detective solves the mystery or realizes who the murderer is?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In many Whodunit mystery stories, there's a scene when the detective (e.g., Hercule Poirot) discovers (or overhears) the final clue (or a phrase another characters says) that makes this detective realize who did the crime.  This is of course before the "Reveal".  Does this event have a name?

Comment: Why not Eureka?

Answer (score 10):

[Epiphany](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/epiphany).

Some excerpts from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_%28feeling%29):

> An epiphany (from the ancient Greek ἐπιφάνεια, epiphaneia, "manifestation, striking appearance") is an experience of sudden and striking realization. Generally the term is used to describe breakthrough scientific, religious or philosophical discoveries, but it can apply in any situation in which an enlightening realization allows a problem or situation to be understood from a new and deeper perspective. ...
>
> The word epiphany originally referred to insight through the divine. ...
>
> Despite its popular image, epiphany is the result of significant work on the part of the discoverer, and is only the satisfying result of a long process. The surprising and fulfilling feeling of epiphany is so surprising because one cannot predict when one's labour will bear fruit.

From Dictionary.com:

> **e·piph·a·ny**
>
> 1. Epiphany
>
>    a. A Christian feast celebrating the manifestation of the divine
>          nature of Jesus to the Gentiles as represented by the Magi.
>
>    b. January 6, on which this feast is traditionally observed.
> 2. A revelatory manifestation of a divine being.
> 3. a. A sudden manifestation of the essence or meaning of something.
>
>    b. A comprehension or perception of reality by means of a sudden intuitive realization: "I experienced an epiphany, a spiritual flash that would change the way I viewed myself" (Frank Maier).
> 4. [Not enumerated by OP]
> 5. (Christianity / Ecclesiastical Terms) the manifestation of a supernatural or divine reality
> 6. any moment of great or sudden revelation [via Church Latin from Greek epiphaneia an appearing, from epi- + phainein to show]

i.e, an *epiphany* has two modes of operation —

1. The party experiencing the epiphany
2. The parties observing the epiphany, hence the moment whereby the parties observe that epiphany.

Answer (score 7):

[***Anagnorisis***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagnorisis) is the term used by Aristotle (and many subsequent critics) for the moment when the protagonist achieves "discovery" or "recognition" or "realization".

Aristotle regards *anagnorisis* as most effective when it leads directly to the [***peripeteia***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripeteia) or "turning point" of a drama, which occasioned considerable debate among old-fashioned theorists of the well-made play about how to handle Shakespeare's typical pyramidal structure, which turns on a pivot somewhere around the end of the third act.

In the murder mystery, likewise, the detective's *anagnorisis* may be distinguished from everybody else's *anagnorisis*, which coincides with the climactic *peripeteia*—what you call the *reveal*. Much of the author's art lies in disguising this earlier recognition, burying it in a barrel of red herrings.

Comment: Very interesting. Perhaps you can expand your answer using the [Mystery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagnorisis#Mystery) section of the WP page. If it is, how is _anagnorisis_ different from _epiphany_?

Comment: @coleopterist  The works discussed in that article don't really fit here, since the detectives fail and there is thus only a single anagorisis. As for *epiphany*, that's been for most of its history a religious term; my impression is that it didn't enter the critical lexicon until James Joyce used it to designate a sudden insight much deeper than the purely intellectual recognition one finds in mysteries.

Comment: @coleopterist -- Anagorisis is much more specific than epiphany; the former is a literary word, the latter in more common usage. Anagorisis also properly refers to the *narrative point* (compare: climax, denoument), where as epiphany refers to the process undergone by the character.

Comment: @StoneyB My apologies. I appear to have missed your reply. Based on your comment as well as AlexFeinman's, the difference is that _epiphany_ is ... spiritual? Or to rephrase, the difference is analogous to that between say, enlightenment and insight? Also, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "since the detectives fail".

Comment: @AlexFeinman Thanks :) Please see my previous comment.

Comment: @coleopterist  In all of the works mentioned at the place you site, the "detective" fails to uncover the truth through his own efforts; in consequence, he comes to the critical recognition at the same time as the rest of the characters and the audience, so there is no such distinction between his recognition and theirs as OP defines. As to ephiphany, Alex says it pretty well.

Comment: @StoneyB So, are those examples all Reveals?

Comment: @coleopterist  They're all the same thing: an *anagnorisis* is a *recognition* is a *reveal*. But OP inquires specifically about works with two distinct recognitions, one the detective's and a later one that of the other characters and the audience.

Comment: @StoneyB Ah! I understand. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

The "aha!" moment? The "Eureka!" moment? The "Dr. House does that thing where he stops mid-conversation and runs out of the room" moment?

Answer (score 0):

The word you're looking for is 'denouement'.

> The **dénouement** (pronounced /deɪnuːˈmɑ̃ː/, /deɪˈnuːmɒn/, or US /deɪːnuˈmɑ̃ː/; French: [denuˈmɑ̃]) comprises events from the end of the falling action to the actual ending scene of the drama or narrative. Conflicts are resolved, creating normality for the characters and a sense of catharsis, or release of tension and anxiety, for the reader. Etymologically, the French word *dénouement* is derived from the Old French word *desnouer*, "to untie", from *nodus*, Latin for "knot". It is the unraveling or untying of the complexities of a plot.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dramatic_structure#D.C3.A9nouement.3B_resolution.2C_revelation.2C_or_catastrophe)</sub>

Comment: Can you include some references that show the word is used in English for the OP's context?

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/denouement not saying it's right, but it's a new term for me, and it *is* related to the topic

Comment: I would never use *dénouement* to describe that particular moment. The *dénouement* is broader. In the context of a detective mystery, it would include not just that moment but many elements, which might (depending on the plot) include a reveal, an arrest, a confession, death of the villain, restoration of property or reputation, etc.